# Lock/Monitor in IActionResult ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new at .NET world. Currently I'm working on ASP.NET MVC "concept editing-sharing" project and I'm stuck on lock/monitor implementation.

I have an IActionResult called EditConcept:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult EditConcept(int id)
{
   return View(_repository.LoadConcept(id));
}
```

which is called when the button "edit" is pressed in ViewConcept view:
ViewConcept

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ViewConcept(int id)
{
   return View(_repository.LoadConcept(id));
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ViewConcept(ConceptModel model)
{
    _repository.SaveConcept(model, model.Id);
    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model ConceptModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ViewConcept";
    if (context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("User") == null)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/User/LogIn");
    }
}

<h1>@Model.Name</h1>

<p>@Model.ConceptSemester.GetDisplayName()</p>

<p>@Model.ConceptText</p>
<input type="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("EditConcept","Concept", new {Id = Model.Id })'" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" />
<input type="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteConcept","Concept", new {Id = Model.Id })'" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" />
@*...*@
```

I have to make sure that only one user could edit the file and restrict other users from reaching that file if someone is already in EditConcept view. How could I achieve this?

P.S. the project is local and uses local database.

GeneralRepository methods for context:

```
private readonly ILogsService _logsService;
private readonly DatabaseContext _database;
private DbSet<ConceptType> _onceptTypes;
public GenericRepository(ILogsService logsService, DatabaseContext database)
{
   _logsService = logsService;
   _database = database;
   _conceptTypes = _database.Set<ConceptType>();
}
public ConspectType LoadConcept(int id)
{
    return _conceptTypes.Find(id);
}

public void SaveConcept(ConceptType concept, int id)
{
    try
    {
       var temp = _conceptTypes.Find(id);
       if (temp == null)
           _conceptTypes.Add(concept);
       else
       {
           _database.Entry(temp).CurrentValues.SetValues(concept);

       }
       _database.SaveChanges();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       _logsService.SaveExceptionInfo(new ExceptionModel(ex));
     }
}
```

Comment: Both the database and file system can provide locking functionality. But do you need to prevent multiple *treads* from concurrently accessing a resource, or multiple *users*? If the later you need to figure out a bunch of things, like what will happen if a user never unlocks the resource.

Comment: I need to prevent multiple users from accessing that view. But is it possible to do it with lock or monitor?

Comment: @gailtye if its from database side, you can "lock" a row by combining `locked_by` column and [`transaction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions). the transaction invoked from application side against the table to ensure atomicity - so only one instance can acquire the lock. you can mitigate orphaned lock by keeping track when was the last time the lock initiated (e.g. with `last_locked` timestamp) and once a certain time passed the lock become eligible again (either implicit or explicitly using "scheduled tasks").

Comment: `lock`/`monitor` it for preventing concurrent threads from accessing a resource. They should not be held for any significant length of time. You should use the database to "lock" your resource, either with a separate table or some columns. You should include information like when it was locked and by whom. And probably both provide timeout based unlocking as well as forcing an unlock by an administrator. There are a bunch of document management systems using something like this, but it will probably be quite difficult to do *Well*.